# Auto resize window when call createWebViewWithRequest in webview

Tags: javascript, macos, cocoa, webview

I want to open many window in webview. I set

```
[webView setUIDelegate: self];
```

when webview load html string that is Javascript. In javascript code, when clicking a button, it will open new window. So, the program call to the

```
- (WebView*)webView:(WebView *)sender createWebViewWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    return sender;
}
```

My issue is the window auto resize when createWebViewWithRequest is called.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After long time research for finding solution, I decide setFrame for window again in this:

```
- (void)webViewShow:(WebView *)sender
{
    [window setFrame:originRect display:YES];
}
```

I solved my issue.